# Adjust coordinate of canvas after screen resize in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, xamarin

I am working on xamarin web view on canvas, From the backend, I am getting some point of(Coordinate). In the backend, they drawing the line and store coordinate as per canvas size (1000X750) Height X Width. But in xamarin web view I have to resize canvas as per device resolution then coordinate will place and show lines.

Please help me how i will achieve.enter image description here

Comment: Can you create an MVCE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve